# A perfect matching decomposition Graph in bipartite graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I'm looking for an algorithm that shows perfect matching decomposition Graph in the bipartite graph. I know the theory of this issue but I can't design this algorithm in Python.

Def : A perfect matching decomposition is a decomposition such that each subgraph Hi in the decomposition is a perfect matching (A perfect matching M in graph G is a matching such that every vertex of G is incident with one of the edges of M )

as I'm a beginner in python could you please guide me about the below code ( how can I test it that its a perfect matching decomposition graph or not? ) 
vertices : 20 and degree should be between 4&8

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx import bipartite

def plotGraph(graph):
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

pos=[(ii[1],ii[0]) for ii in graph.nodes()]
pos_dict=dict(zip(graph.nodes(),pos))
nx.draw(graph,pos=pos_dict,ax=ax,with_labels=True)
plt.show(block=False)
return

def enumMaximumMatching(g):
all_matches=[]
return all_matches

if __name__=='__main__':
g=nx.Graph()
edges=[
    [(1,0), (0,0)],
    [(1,0), (0,8)],
    [(1,0), (0,7)],
    [(1,0), (0,5)],
    [(1,0), (0,6)],
    [(1,1), (0,7)],
    [(1,1), (0,0)],
    [(1,1), (0,9)],
    [(1,1), (0,4)],
    [(1,1), (0,8)],
    [(1,1), (0,6)],
    [(1,2), (0,2)],
    [(1,2), (0,3)],
    [(1,2), (0,8)],
    [(1,2), (0,0)],
    [(1,3), (0,9)],
    [(1,3), (0,7)],
    [(1,3), (0,6)],
    [(1,3), (0,5)],
    [(1,3), (0,4)],
    [(1,3), (0,3)],
    [(1,4), (0,3)],
    [(1,4), (0,0)],
    [(1,4), (0,2)],
    [(1,4), (0,8)],
    [(1,5), (0,2)],
    [(1,5), (0,6)],
    [(1,5), (0,7)],
    [(1,5), (0,8)],
    [(1,5), (0,0)],
    [(1,6), (0,1)],
    [(1,6), (0,7)],
    [(1,6), (0,5)],
    [(1,6), (0,6)],
    [(1,7), (0,4)],
    [(1,7), (0,3)],
    [(1,7), (0,2)],
    [(1,7), (0,1)],
    [(1,8), (0,8)],
    [(1,8), (0,9)],
    [(1,8), (0,7)],
    [(1,8), (0,6)],
    [(1,9), (0,4)],
    [(1,9), (0,3)],
    [(1,9), (0,2)],
    [(1,9), (0,1)],
    [(1,9), (0,5)],
    [(1,6), (0,2)],
    [(1,6), (0,9)],

]

for ii in edges:
    g.add_node(ii[0],bipartite=0)
    g.add_node(ii[1],bipartite=1)

g.add_edges_from(edges)
plotGraph(g)

all_matches=enumMaximumMatching(g)

for mm in all_matches:
    g_match=nx.Graph()
    for ii in mm:
        g_match.add_edge(ii[0],ii[1])
    plotGraph(g_match)
```

Thank you

Comment: I really suggest doing this problem yourself. If you found any problem while doing that, you can post your code with the problem that you've encountered and we are here to help.

Comment: Thank you I edited my question with default of my code but I think it's not true...